# Demo Docusign Connect Notification "Delivered" is not working

Tags: docusignapi

I just have issues with the Connect notification "delivered" from my DocuSign demo account. I'm able to get other notifications like Sent or Completed via Backend and via API. I just tried to get the notification "delivered" via Backend and via API and the log details in the backend shows me this message: "Error loading log details. Try it again."

With other Notifications it shows me the XML with Status sent/completed or something else.
Is this behaviour expected because i just have a demo account? The other notifications like sent and completed seems to work.

This is the message i get if i try to get the notification "delivered".

[image]

And this is the message i get if i try to get the notification "sent" or "complete".

[image]
Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a notification of when an envelope has been delivered to an individual recipient, it is better to use the event user.delivered rather than envelope.delivered.

Also, if you're using the default Connect queuing system, delivered statuses can be subsumed by the completed status if it occurs within a minute or so of the delivered status.

To ensure that you always get every notification, use the SIM queuing system. (Select via Admin tool / Updates screen.)

Comment: Ah thanks now its working as expected. The SIM queuing system was not activated. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is not related to you demo account and you should not see this error.
I tested myself and everything works as expected. Perhaps you can post a screenshot of the error.

Comment: This issue was reported and case CONNECT-1973 was created for your records

Comment: Many thanks. Is there any way I can see the status of the ticket?